# Determine which network adapter has the highest priority in C#?

Tags: c#, networking

If we have multiple network interfaces with the same DNS suffix on a given machine, how do I programatically determine which network interface traffic will be routed over?

For example, I am connected to my companies network via ethernet in office, and connected to the companies network via VPN from inside the office. This sounds stupid, but with the way our networks are connected, if the internal link to our datacenter goes down - I VPN from inside the office to continue development.

Our software has logic to determine our "local ip address" and uses that for authentication logic elsewhere. I know from practice that all my traffic is routed over the VPN when connected - but am struggling with what the correct implementation in code is for robustly choosing the IP address of the adapter with the highest priority.

What I have right now is:

```
var unicastIpAddressInformation = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                .Where(nic => nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up
                                && nic.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback // ...ignore the loopback NIC as we don't want 127.0.0.1 (1 of 2)
                                && nic.Name.IndexOf("loopback", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1 // ...ignore the loopback NIC as we don't want 127.0.0.1 (2 of 2)
                                && nic.Name.IndexOf("virtual", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == -1 // ... ignore virtual NICs so that VMs don't conflict with IP resolution
                )
                .Select(n => n.GetIPProperties())
                // All developer network connections should have the my-company-internal.com suffix
                .Where(ipp => ipp.DnsSuffix.ToLowerInvariant().IndexOf("my-company-internal.com", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                .Where(ipp => ipp.UnicastAddresses.Any(u => u.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
                // Is this order by correct?
                .OrderByDescending(ipp => ipp.GetIPv4Properties().Index)
                .SelectMany(ipp => ipp.UnicastAddresses.Where(ip => ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
                .FirstOrDefault();
```

I know with the IPV4Properties.Index - it is only populated when IPv4 is enabled; I don't know if corresponds to priority or metric, and whether or not they are guaranteed to be distinct.

Comment: With IP, priority is determine by the size of the mask.   The smaller the mask the higher the priority.  Traffic will always go out the route with the smaller mask.  When the primary route is down then data will go out secondary routes.

Comment: I know this - I am connected to my corporate network two times. I have 2 IP addresses each with the same network mask and each with the access to the same routes. I clearly see that the VPN adapter is favored - how can i get the VPN adapters IP address programatically in code?

Comment: CHANGE THE MASK!!!  THERE IS NO OTHER WAY.  THE WINDOWS OPERATING SYSTEM ONLY USES THE MASK!!!

Comment: @jdweng "_Traffic will always go out the route with the smaller mask._" That is exactly backwards. The larger mask is more specific, so a route with a larger mask is used. For example, the default mask (`0.0.0.0` = 0 bits) is the smallest mask, and the default route is the least preferred, while the largest mask (`255.255.255.255` = 32 bits) is the most specific and a route with this mask is the most preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here a few weeks ago. I figured out that the NIC priority is persisted in Windows Registry, and there are a few PowerShell scripts that can give you the NIC order, but not the IP addresses. So, I've written the code below and it worked for me. You can use it to see additional info like dns suffix, gateway address and plus.

You just have to call RMSNetUtils.GetTopIpv4Ip(string.Empty)

```
  public class RMSNetUtils
  {
    private static string _linkagePath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage";

    private static string _interfacesPath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\";

    private static List<string> GetBindingsPriority()
    {
      using (var bindMasterKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(_linkagePath))
      {
        var bind = (string[]) bindMasterKey.GetValue("Bind");
        var deviceList = bind.Select(x => $@"{_interfacesPath}{x.Replace("\\Device\\", string.Empty)}")
          .ToList();

        var result = new List<string>();

        foreach (var device in deviceList)
        {
          using (var bindKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(device))
          {
            var fixIP = (string[])bindKey.GetValue("IPAddress");
            if (fixIP != null)
            {
              result.Add( fixIP.FirstOrDefault());
              continue;
            }

            var dhcpIp = bindKey.GetValue("DhcpIPAddress");
            if (dhcpIp != null)
            {
              result.Add((string) dhcpIp);
            }
          }
        }
        return result;
      }
    }

    private static List<NICInformation> GetFilteredBindings()
    {
      var bindings = GetBindingsPriority();
      var nicsInfo = GetIpList(GetInterNetworkAdapters());
      var result = new List<NICInformation>();
      foreach (var bind in bindings)
      {
        var nicInfo = nicsInfo.FirstOrDefault(y => string.Compare(y.IPv4, bind) == 0);
        if(nicInfo!= null)
          result.Add(nicInfo);
      }

      return result;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<IPAddress> GetInterNetworkAdapters()
    {
      IPHostEntry local = Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty);
      return (from ipa in local.AddressList
        where ipa.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork
        select ipa);
    }

    public static string GetFirstIpv4Ip()
    {
      return GetFirstIpv4Ip(String.Empty);
    }

    private static List<NICInformation> GetIpList(IEnumerable<IPAddress> ips)
    {
      var ipAddresses = ips.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
      var result = new List<NICInformation>();

      foreach (NetworkInterface ni in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
      {
        if (ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
            ni.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
        {
          foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation ip in ni.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
          {
            if (ip.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
            {
              var ipStr = ip.Address.ToString();
              if (ipAddresses.Contains(ipStr))
              {
                var nic = new NICInformation();
                nic.IPv4 = ip.Address.ToString();
                nic.Mask = ip.IPv4Mask.ToString();
                nic.DnsSuffix = ni.GetIPProperties().DnsSuffix;
                var gateway = ni.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses.FirstOrDefault();
                if(gateway!=null)
                  nic.Gateway = gateway.Address.ToString();
                result.Add(nic);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }

      return result;
    }

    public static string GetTopIpv4Ip(string hostName)
    {
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostName))
        return GetFirstIpv4Ip(hostName);
      var item = GetFilteredBindings().FirstOrDefault();

      return item == null ? hostName : item.IPv4;
    }

    public static string GetFirstIpv4Ip(string hostName)
    {
      var ip = string.Empty;
      try
      {
        IPHostEntry local = Dns.GetHostEntry(hostName);
        var result = GetInterNetworkAdapters().FirstOrDefault();

        return result != null ? result.ToString() : hostName;
      }
      catch (SocketException ex)
      {
        ip = hostName;
      }

      return ip;
    }
  }

  public class NICInformation
  {
    public string DnsSuffix {get;set;}
    public string IPv4 {get;set; }

    public string Gateway {get;set;}

    public string Mask {get;set;}
  }
```